# Showing hidden content - smooth appearance

Tags: css

I have put together a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdc4rq6o/) which I'm satisfied has the correct code. 
As you can see, when you hover over the 'a' element I have a div positioned at the bottom raise to show hidden 'text'

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

a:hover .b {
  bottom: 0px;
}

.a {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

.c {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">

      <div class="c">
        A title
      </div>
      <div class="c">
        Read more
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

The problem I have is that the showing of the bottom div is too quick, is there a css property that allows the div to rise up slowly?

There's a similar method used in [this](https://uk.themindgym.com/) website (part way down the page) which I'm trying to replicate.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: `transition: bottom 250ms ease` on your `.b` selector?  Not sure if that's what you're after though

Comment: It was exactly what I needed. Thanks Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the b element in css add the `transition` css property to specify the time it take to associate the style:

```
.b {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;

  transition: bottom 1s;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 1s;
}
```

Comment: A true legend. Thank you. I shall research the transition property now. Thanks again!